# How is the .rodata section of a binary populated in memory?

Tags: c, assembly, memory-management

Assume this simple code:

```
int main(){
 char *s = "hello";
 return 0;
}
```

`s` will look like this in AS:

```
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "hello"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
...
```

Now when we assemble this code and run the binary, `hello` will be put in the `read only` section of memory for us, starting at address `LC0`. Who is doing that? We didn't write any memory relate instructions to accomplish this! is the `loader` somehow doing it when it's loading the binary?

Comment: It's loaded / mapped into memory the same was that the `.text` section containing instructions is.  Instructions can't run either when they're just sitting on disk.

Comment: makes sense, is the loader doing that? I know the world of loaders is huge and very complicated.

Comment: https://lwn.net/Articles/631631/ for Linux ELF executables.  For some more beginner-level descriptions, see the linked duplicates.  The key point is that the kernel basically sets up `mmap` mappings of the executable into the virtual address space of the process running it.

Comment: @Dan Yes, the kernel loads the binary.  How the binary is supposed to be loaded is described by the binary's *program headers* which basically say “load this part of the file to that address with those permissions.”  It's a fairly simple process, really.

Comment: @Dan it is implementation-defined. Every OS and bare metal system will do it differently.

Comment: where it is loaded is based on where you told the linker to put it.  .text, .rodata, .data, .bss, etc you define where you want them in the linker script and thats where they will be.

Comment: If you use some default linker script that comes with the C library for the target and operating system then that defines where it goes.  Who loads it is a combination of how the binary was built and linked and the target operating system and if the bootstrap/linker took advantage of the operating systems loader or not.